# Firestore snapshot missing a field after setDoc is called

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an user document when an user signs in to the app. Here is the code that runs when user clicks login button:

```
export function login() {
signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(result => {
    const user = result.user;
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
    }, {merge: true}); 

}).catch(error => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
})}
```

This code runs when an user wants to add a new task to their task list:

```
export function addTask(description: string) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (!auth.currentUser) {
        //..
    } else {
        const userDoc = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid)
        await updateDoc(userDoc, {
            tasks: arrayUnion({ createdAt: (new Date()).toISOString(), description, done: false })
        })
        resolve(true);
    }
})}
```

Below code gets executed when auth state changes in order to get tasks of the user after they log in.

```
  function updateTasks(){
    getTasks().then(tasks => {
      setTasks(tasks);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      setTasks([]);
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if(user){
        setLoggedIn(true);
      } else setLoggedIn(false);
      updateTasks();
    })
  }, []);
```

Everything works fine to this point. But here is the part of the code that doesn't work as I expected.

Code for fetching tasks:

```
export function getTasks() {
    return new Promise<Task[]>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if(!auth.currentUser){
            reject(new Error("User is not logged in"));
        } else {
            const userDoc = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
            const docSnap = await getDoc(userDoc);
            const userData = docSnap.data() as User;
            console.log("userData", userData);
            resolve(userData.tasks);
          }
        }
    })
}
```

For some reason it only returns the name and email fields of the object. (image1)
[image: developer console]

This is the state of the database when the code executes. (image2)
[image: firestore console]

Comment: Can you try `console.log("userData", JSON.stringify(userData))`. If you see your `tasks` then, it means you're removing them somewhere later on

Comment: Also, are you sure you're looking at the right document? I see two so it could be the other one. You could check by debugging the value of `auth.currentUser.uid`

Comment: Instead of storing tasks with Array in document use sub-collection tasks to store it as tasks so each document in that sub-collection will be the task refer [**`subcollections`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) for better data modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setDoc and getDoc functions running at same time was causing the problem. I've fixed the problem by using a custom callback function instead of using onAuthStateChanged.

```
let onLogin:Function = () => {};

export function setOnLogin(func: Function){
    onLogin = func;
}

export function login() {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then(async (result) => {
        const user = result.user;

        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
        }, {merge: true}); 

        onLogin();

    }).catch(error => {
        //..
    })
}
```

I kept using it for the logout function because there is no such problem when user logouts.

```
useEffect(() => {
      setOnLogin(() => {
        setLoggedIn(true);
        updateTasks();
      })
      
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if(!user){
          setTasks([]);
        }
      })

  }, []);
```